# org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'templates/email/test.vm'

Tags: java, velocity, apache-velocity

My code as follow.

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class");
        ve.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        ve.init();
        Template tempalte = ve.getTemplate("templates/email/test.vm");
```

I am getting following error.

> org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to
>   find resource 'templates/email/test.vm'   at
>   org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1102).....

"template" folder is in my src folder.

> If I directly put the velocity template file into src folder and
>   update as "Template tempalte = ve.getTemplate("test.vm");" it works.

I am using Mac OS, Java 1.8, Eclipse Neon.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks and Regards,
IsuruJ

Comment: Check upper case differences in file or folder

Comment: My vm file path is as /src/templates/email/test.vm

Comment: in my env. templates folder is the root so removing it may work ve.getTemplate("/email/test.vm");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your time. 
This is an ANT project. Mistakenly I couldn't write script to copy templates folder to WEB-INF/classes folder. That was the issue. Both @user7294900 and @soorapadman are correct. The code works now.

Really sorry for the inconvenience.

Best Regards,
IsuruJ

Answer (score 2):

Try to set below variables and check it should work

```
ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class,file");
        ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");
        ve.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "VELLOGGER");
        ve.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        ve.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
```

And your velocity file should be under `resources` folder

The above way i have it my project if that not working try this

I believe your folder structure like `/src/main/java/com/xyz/email/velocity/.`

```
ve.velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER,"classpath");
  ve.velocityEngine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class",ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName())
```

Answer (score 1):

Few Issues may cause it

1. Templates folder is the root of velocity so removing it may work

   ve.getTemplate("/email/test.vm");
2. File with uppercase which is ignored by windows as: folder Email or file Test.vm cannot be found
3. Permissions of new folder/file not allowing read if user not owner

Comment: can it be permission issue of folder? try to chmod email and templates folders