# How to use a text file in Velocity

Tags: velocity

I have a text file with name data.txt which includes Customer's details. I need to send a Msg to each Customer using apache velocity. My file look like this

```
enter code here
First_Name, City, ... 
Rakesh,  Hyderabad,...
Jack,   berlin,... 
....,   ...., ...
```

like this 10000 records are their..
i don't know apache velocity very much.. 
i am unable to load my file in velocity.
my java file

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Velocity.init();
Template t = Velocity.getTemplate("./src/VMDemo.vm");

VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext();

Writer writer = new StringWriter();
t.merge(ctx, writer);

System.out.println(writer);
```

VM file

```
#if ($City == "Hyderabad")
  Hi $first_Name welcome to Hyderabad.
#elseif ($City == "Berling")
  Hi $First_Name welcome to Berlin
#elseif ($City == "Mumbai")
  Hi $First_Name welcome to Mumbai
#else
 Please contact Us
#end
enter code here
the output should be like this..
Hi Rakesh welcome to Hyderabad.
```

Someone please suggest me how to load data and use in velocity.
If Person belongs to some city then the name should be taken dynamically from a file.
Please Someone help me out with this.. just help me including my file in velocity.

Comment: You can add it in the map and access

Comment: @manfromnowhere Will you please help me with some code pls

Comment: I need to understand your whole requirement . You mean to say 10k user you want to send msg? By reading the text file?

Comment: @manfromnowhere i am getting an exception like this SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource './src/apachefilepath.vm' in any resource loader.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource './src/apachefilepath.vm'..

Comment: This means Your vm file not able to find .

Comment: Please check my answer ;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405897/org-apache-velocity-exception-resourcenotfoundexception-unable-to-find-resource/44409087#44409087

Comment: Along with that You have to add this code snippet also to generate the output   `VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext();
    ctx.put("City", "Hyderabad");/ / Hyderabad should be dynamic
    ctx.put("first_name", "Rakesh");// This is also`

Comment: @manfromnowhere  yes.. vm file is not able to find.. I have added but also it throwing an exception

Comment: where did you keep the vm file ? Could you please keep it under `resources/velocity` folder?

Comment: @its working but i need to use my text file(data.txt) which contains 10000 records of different customer. what name and city i am giving in context . its giving output to one customer.. i need to give to all customers

Comment: @Yes you must loop it one by one.

Comment: @manfromnowhere when i am using #include("D:\\temp\\data.txt") in vm file its throwing an exception like unable to load a file.. how can i used my data.txt file velocity is my main problem.. its a task for me.. and i am very new to java and velocity :(

Comment: Did you put your `text file` under velocity folder ?

Comment: I think you can't use it like  `#include("D:\\temp\\data.txt")`  instead you can put under velocity folder and try  `#include("data.txt")`